# Should I be using .live(...)?

Tags: jquery, events, live

When I use jQuery to attach events to elements, I typically do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some_id').click(function() {
        // Do some stuff
    });
});
```

However, I've seen a number of examples that do it like so:

```
$('#some_id').live('click', function() {
    // Do some stuff
});
```

(Almost always without the `ready` wrapper.)

Is there a drawback to one way or the other, if the elements are already in the page and aren't going anywhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are numerous drawbacks to `.live()`, such that I'd restrict its use to when:

1. a large number of elements need to be bound to the same event handler, or
2. elements are frequently added or removed.

`.live()` works by attaching an event handler to `document`, and checking if `event.target` matches the given selector. This results in:

- unnecessary checks against the selector when elements **other than** `#some_id` are clicked.
- no opportunity to `stopPropagation()` of the event since it has already reached the root (although you can still `preventDefault()`).
- similarly, click handlers attached to **parents** of `#some_id` (via `.click()` or `.bind()`) that `return false` or `stopPropagation()` will silence handlers attached via `.live()`, as the event will no longer reach the root.
- it can **only** be used with a **selector** (string).
- unexpected event handling order can result since events will be fired in the order they are bound, and not in bubbling order (child to parent).
- the event is not removed if the element is removed.
- while rare, you cannot `.triggerHandler()` on the element.

Answer (score 2):

The drawback is that the event handling is "slower". `live()` attaches a click handler to the document root and makes use of [*event bubbling*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to capture the events from the specified elements.

So instead of the event being handled directly by the element it was raised on, it has to bubble up the whole DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `.live` when the DOM elements to which you are attaching the events could be modified/replaced. It has an additional overhead as it will listen for DOM modifications. So use it only if you know that the DOM elements will be modified in order to avoid the need of reattaching them. For example if you use AJAX to replace portions of your page with some new content and this portions contained DOM elements to which you was attaching events you need to use `.live`. Otherwise use standard `.click`.

Comment: *It has an additional overhead as it will listen for DOM modifications* that is wrong. `live` attaches an event listener to the document root and makes use of event bubbling.

Comment: @Felix Kling, and this comes at no cost? But probably under modern browsers there really won't be much difference.

Comment: The only cost is that it takes longer for the event to be processed. But `live` doesn't do anything if a new element is inserted. It does not matter if it costs more or not, you explanation *why* it costs more is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You only need `.live()` if there will be dinamically added elements. If the DOM is static, you're safe with `.click()`.

Some more caveats on using `.live()` from the official documentation:

- DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to `.live()`. Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above.
- To stop further handlers from executing after one bound using `.live()`, the handler must return false. Calling `.stopPropagation()` will not accomplish this.
- In jQuery 1.3.x only the following JavaScript events (in addition to custom events) could be bound with `.live()`: `click`, `dblclick`, `keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup`, `mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseout`, `mouseover`, and `mouseup`.

Answer (score 0):

`.live` works like a `*live*` node list, which means that nodes you add *after* the call (matching the css selector) will also be added the handler.

The first call only adds the handler to the node(s) matching the css selector *at the time of the call*.

In your example, your css selector is `#some_id`.  If you later on add a few nodes with exactly the same id (i.e. some_id), those nodes will be added the handler with `.live()` but not with the first call.

Comment: If i added several nodes with the same ID, i'd expect problems.  :)  IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: True. This is the case for the question. Most `.live()` calls, however, are done on css selectors that are much less trivial, esp. selecting on classes.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for using `.live()` method can be a dynamically added, created or loaded DOM elements.
For example, you dynamically, through AJAX call, loading a form and you want to bind to "submit" event of this form some callback function. You can do this manually when process of loading form is done or you can just use `.live()` method once and forget about handling this form every time when it loaded.

p.s.
there was troubles with `.live()` and `sumbit`, but i hope they were fixed.

Comment: So if my clickable element is there in the HTML and isn't going to be added or loaded later, .live() doesn't do anything for me?

Answer (score -1):

you could use .delegate http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: What are the up- and/or downsides to using it?  IE: why/when would i want to use it rather than .live() or good old .click()?

Comment: I use it in place of .live its a bit more specific. I found when I had a very deep DOM structure .live was really slow becuase the events would bubble right up to body. as an example say you had a ul and added li with links (like a menu) you would have $('ul').delegate('a','click', function(){//do something}); with this bit of code I could add more <li a> elements and and if i clicked the ul will detect the clicked element. have a read through the docs